# Not able to connect to perforce server outside of localhost

Tags: port, port-forwarding, perforce

My setup is a Qwest PK5000 router with a Linksys router running Tomato.

I have DMZ pointed towards my router. (The server is on the tomato router).

I tried my applications that open up sockets and Utorrent (port 6883)
and I ended having to do advanced port forwarding and forward specific ports in addition to having DMZ on my router.

The problem is that I cannot connect to perforce when on another machine on the LAN or off.
Any ideas? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start p4d do you set the listen port (-p option) to be my_hostname:1666?

I have had this issue before when I started p4d with -p 127.0.0.1:1666.

Answer (score 1):

What port is p4d running on? The default is 1666.

Comment: It's running on 1666.
I can connect if I do 127.0.0.1:1666 but anywhere outside of the local loopback and it times out.